# Using variables from different properties file in spring application properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have multiple application-[profile]properties files for different profiles but all of them use the same DB.
I don't want to have the username and password hardcoded in each file, instead I want to have them as variables in some sort of global variables file.
Is is possible to do something like that without using system environment variables?

Comment: Have it in `application.properties` file.

Comment: How can I access variables in an application.properties file from another application.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Karthikeyan suggested, you can put your username and password only in the application.properties file. The file application.properties will always be loaded even if you use an environment-specific property file like application-dev.properties. However, if there is a property collision, the environment-specific property file takes precedence.

Comment: The problem I have with that solution is that the properties have different names but the same values. For example db.dev.username and db.prod.username.

Comment: You can create a property **db.username=myusername** in application.properties, and then in application-dev.properties you can use **db.dev.username=${db.username}**